# How can I change my DocumentRoot without breaking PHP?

Tags: php, windows, apache

I had my development machine set up just fine and everything worked perfectly. But then I needed to shuffle some folders around and in doing so needed to change my apache document root.

It was d:/htdocs
It is now d:/web/htdocs

I've updated it both times in httpd.conf; at DocumentRoot d:/htdocs and <Directory "d:/htdocs">

The problem is that now PHP is not working. Apache has changed the root okay but even a simple phpinfo() script doesn't work.

What's going on?

I really don't understand why this would cause apache to be unable to find php. All paths referring to php from httpd.conf are absolute. Am I right in thinking it's a problem with apache finding php rather than php being able to find apache?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try restarting apache ?

Comment: Depending on how you run PHP, you may have to update a directory there as well. And what does "PHP doesn't work" mean exactly? Do you see the unparsed code?

Comment: I've restarted apache and my computer several times now. I don't see unparsed code, I don't see anything.

Comment: Apologies, it turns out I was just too tired when testing this and just made a couple of really stupid mistakes.

I was using <? phpinfo(); ?>
rather than <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error.log and the access.log file

Comment: yeah that could be a good starting point, I would also recommend installing something like webmin, but dont know how easy it will be to setup on windows. It does simplify things a lot.